# Combined Table of contents from several documents

Tags: google-docs

I'd like to have a list of headings in alphabetical order for easy overview of a project.

Is there a way to create a document that would contain all Tables of contents from other selected documents?

Comment: (If interested, for Microsoft Word: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/create-a-table-of-contents-for-multiple-documents-HA102322881.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but docs have been more convenient aside from this feature.